# LibGdx Hiero fonts are coming out crooked?

Tags: java, libgdx

[image: the text doesn't "sit" on a straight line]

I'm using a Bitmap font (Hiero to produce the text), but for some reason, the text isn't straight as you can see above: notice how the 'a' in the word "bad" is below the 'b' and 'd'. The letter 'd' in the word "and" sits way higher than 'a' and 'n'.

How come this is the case? Is there any method to fix this? Is it an issue with the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font.setUseIntegerPositions(false);`